# No active warehouse selected in the current session - Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, data-warehouse, snowflake-schema, dbt

I am following this tutorial: https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/data_engineering_with_dbt/#4

when I try to run this in a worksheet:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."DATASETS"
 WHERE "DatasetName" ILIKE 'US Stock%'
    OR "DatasetName" ILIKE 'Exchange%Rates%';
```

I get an error that `No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.`

I am logged in as TESTUSER and as SECURITYADMIN role. I have also given necessary permissions:

[image]

What can I try? I tried to run this `USE WAREHOUSE DBT_PROD_WH` in a separate worksheet but it doesn't make any difference. I am not sure which warehouse I am supposed to use and with which role specifically

Comment: Don't do it in a separate worksheet.  Run the `USE WAREHOUSE DBT_PROD_WH;` command in the active worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hit the same issue, following the same tutorial... basically there are no warehouses by default on the Snowflake account.

My approach was to identify how I can create/manage the warehouse in this case.

I've used the [CREATE WAREHOUSE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-warehouse.html) command (i.e. `CREATE WAREHOUSE FIRST_WH`)

This got automatically selected as my current warehouse after it was created:
[image]

From there, just continue the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The warehouse has to be set incontext of current session:

```
SELECT CURRENT_WAREHOUSE();
```

If it returns null then, it could be set up in WebUI.
[Using Worksheets for Queries - Overview of Features](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html#overview-of-features), setting the warehouse using item number 4

> Dropdown menu:
>
> Change the current database, schema, or warehouse for the current worksheet without losing your work.
>
> Resume/suspend or resize your current warehouse.

---

Alternatively in the same worksheet:

```
USE WAREHOUSE <warehouse_name>;

SELECT * 
  FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."DATASETS"
 WHERE "DatasetName" ILIKE 'US Stock%'
    OR "DatasetName" ILIKE 'Exchange%Rates%';
```

Comment: I've tried using your suggestion, but the new UI is nothing like the one depicted in that documentation link (as of today's date anyways!). I found the command `CREATE WAREHOUSE` does the job instead.

Comment: @FAB Image in question suggests using Classic WebUI, thus the link in the answer. The Snowsight also offers similar feature [Context selector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-query.html#snowsight-query-context-selector). The virtual warehouse should already exists and necessary permissions granted to active role

Comment: I'm still learning the UI, and until you've mentioned `Snowsight` didn't realise the new UI actually has a name, so thank you for that. Using the context selector, the only warehouse I have an option to choose at the moment, is the one I've just created.

Comment: @FAB That is true, you could choose only existing VW you have granted permission. The UI could be choosen at profile level: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73893487/5070879 Snowsight is newer one so using it as default is good choice.