# Can I switch my default editor to Snowsight?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I login via SSO and it loads up the classic UI.  After SSO login I'm sent to specific url like https://company.us-east.snowflakecomputing.com/console#/internal/worksheet.

Is it possible for *me* in Snowflake to change my default editor from classic to Snowsight so it automatically loads after the SSO login?  I'm not an Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this feature is available where the default landing UI would be
Snowsight instead of the current Classic UI. Please reach out to Support team to get more details on this.

Comment: Thank you, I also spoke to our team about changing the SSO link since we are early in our journey.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change Default Experience under Profile:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's nothing in your SSO setup to prevent this, if you log in using the following URL pattern, it should take you to Snowsight instead of getting there from the classic UI:

```
https://app.snowflake.com/<REGION>/<ACCOUNT>
```

Your sample URL will take you to the classic UI. To change it, go from this:

```
https://company.us-east.snowflakecomputing.com/console#/internal/worksheet.
```

To this:

```
https://app.snowflake.com/us-east/company
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a single click SSO link via a Customer identity and access management (CIAM) tool.  I'll move to direct bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start with the correct URL for Snowsight on your account, rather than the URL for the classic UI, which us what you are showing in your question

Unless your set-up is unusual (and not pure SSO) then SSO doesn’t change URLs - it just returns you  to your original URL once you have logged in.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a single click SSO link via a Customer identity and access management (CIAM) tool.  I'll move to direct bookmarks.