# How to switch between classy webui and snowsight [Snowflake]

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a trial account on snowflake, unable to find the way. By default I get into the mordern UI only.

Researched documentation, but unable to find the right way.

Comment: Look under the "Help & Support" link on the left pane. There should be a link for "Classic Console"

Comment: It is possible to choose [default experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73893487/5070879)

Comment: @GregPavlik that link has disappeared.. but LukaszSzozda solution still works

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Interesting... I still have it on my lab accounts.

Comment: @GregPavlik yes, I had it recently up till my current trial also..

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the below part in the subdirectory in your URL

```
Add login?disableDirectLogin=true to https://AccountName.Region.snowflakecomputing.com/console/login?disableDirectLogin=true
```

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/FAQ-the-Classic-UI-button-has-disappeared-from-Snowsight

Also, from the Profile page, you can switch to Classic UI using the 'Classic Console' option available in the bottom left corner.